# Kernel pppd task hung after running over serial port

Tags: linux, kernel, ppp

I am trying to run the `ppp` daemon on the console port of my board which has p2020 processor with Linux kernel 2.6.32.
After running `ppp` interface `ppp0` is not coming up and I get an error `pppd blocked for more than 120 sec`. I am not able to debug this.

How can I prevent this error from occurring?

syslog output given below.

```
INFO: task pppd:2957 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
pppd D 0fe61c98 0 2957 2953 0x00000002
Call Trace:
[eec93d10] [c021ace4] n_tty_set_termios+0x3f8/0x59c (unreliable)
[eec93dd0] [c0007920] __switch_to+0x54/0xb0
[eec93de0] [c0381e8c] schedule+0x1f0/0x2f8
[eec93e20] [c021f308] tty_ldisc_ref_wait+0x6c/0xb0
[eec93e60] [c0218888] tty_ioctl+0x13c/0x9dc
[eec93e90] [c00b0aa4] vfs_ioctl+0x34/0x8c
[eec93ea0] [c00b0cc8] do_vfs_ioctl+0x88/0x72c
[eec93f10] [c00b13ac] sys_ioctl+0x40/0x74
[eec93f40] [c000f998] ret_from_syscall+0x0/0x3c
INFO: task pppd:2957 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
pppd D 0fe61c98 0 2957 2953 0x00000002
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in this particular version of the Kernel. It was patched in versoin 2.6.34. This was the ticket opened up against the Kernel: [Bug 16206 - PROBLEM: PPP and other serial port related application hangs in kernel space](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16206).

Either you'll need to backport the patch yourself or move up to a newer version of the Kernel.

Comment: thank you for your reply.I applied that patch few days back on 2.6.32,but same issue reproduced again.I will check again.